# Parse error on line 1: { #networkports "l ----------^ Expecting 'STRING', '}'

Tags: json, linux, syntax-error

> Parse error on line 1: {         #networkports     "l ----------^ Expecting 'STRING', '}'

The error is above, lines one and beyond are below... help please!

```
 {
      # network ports
       "listen" : [
            # binary protocol (default), port 8342
             { "port" : 8342 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the line

```
# network ports
```

which is not valid json syntax (json does not support comments). So you need to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out with deleting "network ports" and first line is now "listen"